# Расположить текст в Tkinter поверх прямоугольников в Змейке

Tags: python, tkinter

Написал рабочую Змейку на Python с помощью фреймворка Tkinter, принцип в том, что на Canvas у меня рисуются прямоугольники, представляющие сегменты змейки, а ко всему прочему в разных случаях ещё и выводится текст (если нажали на паузу или проиграли и хотим рестартнуть), вот только злосчастный текст трусливо прячется за сегментами-прямоугольниками (пример на скрине). Вот хотел узнать, возможно ли этот самый текст вывести поверх сегментов или же придётся пользоваться костылями по типу вывода прямоугольника-родителя для этого текста?
Вот немного кода по заданию игрового поля и текстовых сообщений, а также класс Segment, отвечающий за отрисовку частей змейки:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Snake')

cnvs_field = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH, bg='black')
cnvs_field.grid()
cnvs_field.focus_set()

txt_game_over = cnvs_field.create_text(
    WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2 - SEG_SIZE,
    text='HUMANITY IS DOOMED.\n'
         'YOU CANNOT REDO.\n'
         'OR CAN YOU?..',
    justify=tk.CENTER,
    font='Arial 20',
    fill='DarkOrange1',
    state='hidden'
)
```

Класс Segment:

```
class Segment:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = cnvs_field.create_rectangle(x, y, x+SEG_SIZE, y+SEG_SIZE,
                                                fill='green3')
```

[image: Змейка перекрывает сообщение о проигрыше и кнопку рестарта]

Comment: план б. писать текст каждый цикл/после перерисовки змеи.